# How do I implement a callback to update Jotai state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jotai

I currently have an asynchronous `connectWallet` function embedded within a React component (Modal Form) that I want to make global/available for multiple components.

Unfortunately, the function itself references jotai atoms that exist within the Modal Form.

```
export function ConnectWalletModal({ onClose }: IConnectWalletModalProps) {
  const [, setWalletAddress] = useAtom(walletAddressAtom);
  const [, setWalletBalance] = useAtom(walletBalanceAtom);
  const [isWalletConnected, setIsWalletConnected] = useAtom(
    isWalletConnectedAtom
  );

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      //CONNECTION LOGIC...


      //Jotai
      setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
      setWalletBalance(+bal);
      setIsWalletConnecting(false);
      setIsWalletConnected(true);

      onClose();
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

I feel like the easiest way is to export the connectWallet function outside of the component. I won't have access to the jotai atoms but maybe I can add an "onConnectSuccessful" callback function to the connectWallet arguments.

Then wherever I call connectWallet, I can pass an extra argument which will be a function that accepts the address and balance as arguments and sets the jotai state.

Problem is that I am not sure how to structure this syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a writable atom?

Something like this:

```
const walletConnectionAtom = atom(
  null, // no "get" function, so it's a writable atom
  async (_, set) => {
    try {
      //CONNECTION LOGIC...

      //Jotai
      set(walletAddressAtom, accounts[0]);
      set(walletBalanceAtom , +bal);
      set(isWalletConnectedAtom, true);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
)
```

then in your component (or any other component for that matter):

```
export function ConnectWalletModal({ onClose }: IConnectWalletModalProps) {
  const connectWallet = useSetAtom(walletConnectionAtom)

  return <button onClick={() => connectWallet().then(onClose)} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom destructure and update fn

```
const updateAppState = (updates) => {
  setAppState((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...updates }));   
};
```